# How to prove this inequality $\sqrt{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+\sqrt{\frac{bcd}{a}})}+2\sqrt{abcd} \ge ab+bc+cd+da+ac+bd$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a,b,c,d>0$. Show that
$$\sqrt{\left(a+\sqrt{\dfrac{bcd}{a}}\right)\left(b+\sqrt{\dfrac{acd}{b}}\right)\left(c+\sqrt{\dfrac{abd}{c}}\right)\left(d+\sqrt{\dfrac{abc}{d}}\right)}+2\sqrt{abcd}\ge ab+bc+cd+da+ac+bd$$

My idea: make use of
$$a+\sqrt{\dfrac{bcd}{a}}=a+\dfrac{\sqrt{abcd}}{a}\ge 2\sqrt{\sqrt{abcd}}$$

It is said this inequality can be proved using AM-GM( Cauchy-Schwarz) inequality. But I can't.

Thank you for you help in proving it.

Comment: Why have you put Cauchy-Schwarz inside brackets?AM-GM is quite different from Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: As the inequality is homogenous, setting $abcd=1$ gives $$\sqrt{(a^2+1)(b^2+1)(c^2+1)(d^2+1)}+2\geq\sum_{sym}ab.$$ Cauchy-Schwarz becomes recognizable, but the difficult part seems to be the $+2$.
Not sure how to go from here. I have a few ideas (If you want me to in can write them in an answer but I don't think they're very valuable.)

Answer (score 7):

Solution:
Use the following factorization $\prod_{cyc}(a^2+x^2) = \prod_{cyc}(x+ai)\prod_{cyc}(x-ai)$ to see that $$\prod_{cyc}(a^2+x^2) = (x^4+abcd - x^2(ab+ac +bc +cd +da+db) )^2 +$$
$$ + (x^3(a+b+c+d)-x(abc+bcd+cda+dab))^2$$, where $x$ is arbitrary number.
If you let $x = (abcd)^{\frac 14}$, and ignore the second term on the right  hand side of the equality, then our desired inequality follows. Inequality holds if and only if $$(ab-cd)(ac-bd)(ad-bc) = 0$$

Comment: "x is arbitrary number"? Please check e.g., $x=0$.

Comment: @RiverLi there is obviously a typo in the first summand. now it's correct.

Comment: (+1) It is a nice solution.

Comment: @RiverLi thanks, but to be fair I did come up with this problem in this way. Only one student solved it at the competition by brute force-expanding if I remember correctly.

Comment: Since the competition is time-limited, brute force method is easier to deal with. Similarly, the buffalo way is often powerful, but is considered inelegant.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG, assume $abcd = 1$. The desired inequality is written as
$$\sqrt{(a^2+1)(b^2+1)(c^2+1)(d^2+1)} + 2 \ge ab + bc + cd + da + ac + bd.$$
Since $ab + bc + cd + da + ac + bd \ge 6$, it suffices to prove that
$$(a^2+1)(b^2+1)(c^2+1)(d^2+1) - (ab + bc + cd + da + ac + bd - 2)^2 \ge 0.$$
Using $d = \frac{1}{abc}$, we have
$$\mathrm{LHS} = \frac{(ab - 1)^2(bc-1)^2(ca-1)^2}{a^2b^2c^2}.$$
We are done.

Comment: Hi there, Mr. Li

Comment: I need the help

Comment: Can you find the decreasing function(s) there ?

Comment: @hd_30102 Thanks. I will take a look at it.

Comment: I'm kind of silly, my favor for you is too extraordinary, I'm so glad and thankful to you, thank you so much.

Comment: @hd_30102 Actually, many users here will help you. I am not sure that I can help you.